# How can find specific element in jquery object?

Tags: jquery, object

How can I extract pathmp3 from blow String?

```
[
    {
    "id":2578774,
    "word":"apple",
    "addtime":"2013-11-04 21:40:05",
    "hits":6796,
    "username":"JerrySun",
    "sex":"m",
    "country":"United States",
    "code":"en",
    "langname":"English",
    "pathmp3":"http:\/\/apifree.forvo.com\/audio\/3l2h333f1p3d1h2a363f2j3b2h2j282e3f373m2b3f2k1g31231n3m3i3l331n2637361i3g393c293j243i3l2c3o341b2p291j2k1n1l1o3m233p2e1g1h2i343m25_2925241j3a1j3f342e232c3k2k212n2i29263p352i3n1t1t",
    "pathogg":"http:\/\/apifree.forvo.com\/audio\/28313h382e3j2g3k3k231b311j3k39281l1h1m1g2d1h3m2h3g3k1o2h3n2m273325332l3e331g2n2j2l2k293b3d3k2f3a322k2l1p2521232a232a2l2n1l2p2q3l_2i253a2o1f233626273i3d2e2k243j231j243m2a28371t1t",
    "rate":5,
    "num_votes":5,
    "num_positive_votes":5
    }
];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript

Comment: Thank you for your Update! 
I ask this question cuz here i take this string from server. in those answer that you recommended , the user send Ajax with callback element that make it easy to read answer. but i made this in C# and send the string to client. then I try to read String with jquery.

Comment: In that case youcan use `JSON.parse(string);` to convert the string to JSON object.

Comment: Or Use Xml and Send answer to client side ! Simple, Faster and Better Performance. Thank You . :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can access this value with arr[0].pathmp3

```
var arr= [
    {
    "id":2578774,
    "word":"apple",
    "addtime":"2013-11-04 21:40:05",
    "hits":6796,
    "username":"JerrySun",
    "sex":"m",
    "country":"United States",
    "code":"en",
    "langname":"English",
    "pathmp3":"http:\/\/apifree.forvo.com\/audio\/3l2h333f1p3d1h2a363f2j3b2h2j282e3f373m2b3f2k1g31231n3m3i3l331n2637361i3g393c293j243i3l2c3o341b2p291j2k1n1l1o3m233p2e1g1h2i343m25_2925241j3a1j3f342e232c3k2k212n2i29263p352i3n1t1t",
    "pathogg":"http:\/\/apifree.forvo.com\/audio\/28313h382e3j2g3k3k231b311j3k39281l1h1m1g2d1h3m2h3g3k1o2h3n2m273325332l3e331g2n2j2l2k293b3d3k2f3a322k2l1p2521232a232a2l2n1l2p2q3l_2i253a2o1f233626273i3d2e2k243j231j243m2a28371t1t",
    "rate":5,
    "num_votes":5,
    "num_positive_votes":5
    }
];

alert(arr[0].pathmp3);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have one `Object` in your `String` which is actually an `Array`.

Simply do `alert(myString[0].pathmp3);`

`myString[0]` will access the first (and only) object, and `.pathmp3` appended to it will access the `pathmp3` property of that object.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
var myString= [
    {
    "id":2578774,
    "word":"apple",
    "addtime":"2013-11-04 21:40:05",
    "hits":6796,
    "username":"JerrySun",
    "sex":"m",
    "country":"United States",
    "code":"en",
    "langname":"English",
    "pathmp3":"http:\/\/apifree.forvo.com\/audio\/3l2h333f1p3d1h2a363f2j3b2h2j282e3f373m2b3f2k1g31231n3m3i3l331n2637361i3g393c293j243i3l2c3o341b2p291j2k1n1l1o3m233p2e1g1h2i343m25_2925241j3a1j3f342e232c3k2k212n2i29263p352i3n1t1t",
    "pathogg":"http:\/\/apifree.forvo.com\/audio\/28313h382e3j2g3k3k231b311j3k39281l1h1m1g2d1h3m2h3g3k1o2h3n2m273325332l3e331g2n2j2l2k293b3d3k2f3a322k2l1p2521232a232a2l2n1l2p2q3l_2i253a2o1f233626273i3d2e2k243j231j243m2a28371t1t",
    "rate":5,
    "num_votes":5,
    "num_positive_votes":5
    }
];

alert(myString[0].pathmp3);
```